Is it possible to implement a ninja build system in qmake?
I have a task: to build a project for a linux system using ninja, and for the rest using a Makefile.
I wrote an example .pro file:
linux {
 QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS += ninja

 ninja.output = ${QMAKE_FILE_BASE}.ninja
 ninja.commands = ninja -C $$OUT_PWD
 ninja.depend_command = ninja -t deps

 QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += ninja
} else {
 TARGET = main
 SOURCES += main.cpp vector2d.cpp
 HEADERS += ivector.h vector2d.h
}

however, it requires the build.ninja file.
Is it possible to create such a .pro file that will generate a file?ninja, or just build a project using ninja, but without a file.ninja?
